# Kubuntu 15.04 Can't Change Display Configuration

Tags: ati, 15.04, display-resolution

I upgraded to Kubuntu 15.04 recently and all was fine. Yesterday my screen started jumping so I rebooted. It fixed the jumping but since then my screen resolution has been screwed up and I can't change it. There is no option on display configuration to adjust resolution or even add a new display, it just contains default screen with a fixed resolution.

I am using the recommended Xorg AMD/ATI driver.
I have generated a xorg.conf file and added the correct resolution - this doesn't work.
I have edited the kscreen config (~/.local/share/kscreen) but I suspect it gets overwritten on a shutdown so any edits I make are lost. There are two config files in this folder, the older one contains the correct resolution but it does not get used.

I've trawled the net but can't find any answers. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is now a confirmed bug but is yet to be assigned for resolution:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-config-systemd/+bug/1445395